# PHP Select all from current and future dates only

Tags: php, mysql

I need to list and records in a table where "theDate" field is either current or future.

The "theDate" field will contain a date in this format: Year-month-day ... so something like: 2014-12-31

So I have `SELECT * FROM events` but I need the WHERE part so I can get only current and future dates.

How can I do this?

Comment: The answer is going to depend on whether MySQL and PHP are running within the same timezone and whether timezone is indeed a factor.

Comment: Also, are you storing the date inside a DATE column or is it a (VAR)CHAR field?

Comment: [If you want your query to be cacheable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726913/mysql-cache-and-date-functions), you should not use the `NOW()` or `CURDATE()` functions, but should send the actual date (using PHP's `date()` function) in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a MySQL keyword called NOW() and a simple greater than or equal to test

```
WHERE theDate >= NOW()
```

Comment: Not if like he said the theDate field only contains a data and not a time component.

Comment: Are you saying that MySQL compares DATE<->DATETIME as DATE<->DATE? Almost certain you should use `DATE(NOW())` to make a sane comparison (assuming today lasts the whole day).

Comment: You had me worried, just tested it and it does as I expected on `date` columns but not on `datetime` columns as you suspected.

Comment: Thanks for testing that; I would still argue that it's somewhat sloppy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE date_column >= CURDATE();
```

date_column being the name of your column that contains the date.

CURDATE() returns the current date.